# How to transmit data via USB HID(/dev/hidg0)?

Tags: usb

I'm using Atmel sama5d3x serials. I implement device to USB HID device (as keyboard). Already try the configuration of kernel for both USB HID to g_hid.o(built-in_ or g_hid.ko module), then Windows can identify as keyboard, event device has interface (`/dev/hidg0`) there.

How can I transmit data via this interface?

Kernel version : 3.14

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is "how can i transmit data via the interface from the Linux".

From Linux userspace, you can open `/dev/hidg0` with mode `wb` and then simply `write` to this file descriptor.

For instance in Python:

```
with open('/dev/hidg0', 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(data_to_sent_over_hid)
```